# Disable Overscan AMD Radeon 7600M Windows 10

Tags: amd-radeon, overscan

My problem is that I need to connect my laptop to my HDTV via HDMI, however I cannot stop it from overscanning. I have done much research, finding no solution. I found two different registry edits that supposedly fix the issue, however neither of them work. One involved searching for the display resolution and modifying the value of the found key. The other was to change/create a couple of keys to disable over- and under-scanning. I have also tried enabling underscanning. The other fix was to adjust the overscan slider in CCC, however there is no such setting (I can only adjust switchable graphics, nothing to do with actual display settings. It seems for some reason Intel HD graphics (which I have no clue why that's even on there, that should be disabled?) is taking control. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Since it is the TV that is overscanning, you should try to fix the TV.

Comment: I checked that first. There is no way as there are practically no settings at all in settings menu (basic picture adjustment like picture profile, that's about it). Only solution is in computer

Comment: What is the make and model of the TV?

Comment: dick smith GE6823

Comment: I have no idea about that particular model, but I have an older phillips 720 lcd tv , that has a minor overscan that can shift some with the remote, and there is nothing in that particular tv that will stop it. Works great as a tv and causes no problem with tv, but it is inconvienent for the computer, so it stays tv.